# Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories

Tags: solidity, brownie, chainlink

I'm trying to deploy an interface from Chainlink and I have in my solidity contract the import for the AggregatorV3Interface:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

and the following remappings in the brownie-config.yaml:

```
dependencies:
   - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1

compiler:
  solc:
    remapping:
     - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

But while compiling the contract `brownie compile`, I run into the error:

```
contracts/Lottery.sol:5:1: ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

It looks like Solidity cannot find the interface.
Can anybody explain to me where exactly these chainlink contracts are taken from?
Do I need to clone the chainlink repository locally?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I found kind of a solution, maybe helpful for somebody else.

1. use yarn to install @chainlink/contracts

```
yarn add @chainlink/contracts
```

this creates a subdirectory node_modules/ including @chainlink/contracts.

2. change the import to

```
import "node_modules/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

Like this I can compile the contract in brownie without errors.